# Applescript: search Google for iTunes track lyrics

Tags: search, location, applescript

I want a script to search Google for the lyrics of the currently playing song. Why doesn't the following work?

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set trackArtist to artist of current track
    set trackName to name of current track
end tell
set search to trackArtist & " - " & trackName & " lyrics"
open location "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & search
```

If I "return search", I can see the variable is set correctly. And if I replace "search" in the last line with "test lyrics" the browser opens as expected. But the script above performs no action whatsoever, nor does it return any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot that most browsers decode the URL in the address field and before requested they encode the URL again before. So what you need to do is encode the url too.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set trackArtist to artist of current track
    set trackName to name of current track
end tell
open location "http://www.google.com/search?q=" & rawurlencode(trackArtist & " - " & trackName & " lyrics")

on rawurlencode(theURL)
    set PHPScript to "<?php echo rawurlencode('%s');?>"
    set theURL to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theURL & " | sed s/\\'/\\\\\\\\\\'/g"
    return do shell script "printf " & quoted form of PHPScript & space & quoted form of theURL & " | php"
end rawurlencode
```

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you. I would have never known how to do the encoding. I wonder why so many slashes are needed for sed s/\\'/\\\\\\\\\\'/g

Comment: Yes, I know that the sed command is confusing. Every time you enter a new environment you need to escape the backslashes so in AppleScript it would be 2 but when needed in the shell it would be 4 and eventually we need to escape a single quote in php and therefore we need 8 (2^3=8). As you can see even songs or artists with a single quote in their name will be encoded correctly. This wouldn't happend if we didn't use the sed command this way.